# VSCode Terminal environment different than regular terminal environment

Tags: linux, bash, visual-studio-code, terminal

I've finished installing a new Linux box with latest Mint version. To my surprise, VSCode terminal is not able to run commands that can be run from a regular terminal. What I have found so far is that my user from the regular terminal seems to belong to a set of groups, and the exact same user from the VSCode terminal belongs to other groups. How can that be possible?

Regular terminal:

```
$ id
uid=1000(juanfer) gid=1000(juanfer) grupos=1000(juanfer),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),115(lpadmin),136(sambashare),999(docker)

# number of files in /usr/bin
$ ls -l /usr/bin | wc -l
2523

$ pwd
/home/juanfer

$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="21.1 (Vera)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE="ubuntu debian"
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 21.1"
VERSION_ID="21.1"
HOME_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.linuxmint.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
VERSION_CODENAME=vera
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

VSCode terminal:

```
$ id
uid=1000(juanfer) gid=1000(juanfer) grupos=1000(juanfer),65534(nfsnobody)

# number of files in /usr/bin
$ ls -l /usr/bin | wc -l
1064

$ pwd
/home/juanfer

$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Freedesktop SDK"
VERSION="22.08 (Flatpak runtime)"
VERSION_ID=22.08
ID=org.freedesktop.platform
PRETTY_NAME="Freedesktop.org SDK 22.08 (Flatpak runtime)"
BUG_REPORT_URL=https://gitlab.com/freedesktop-sdk/freedesktop-sdk/issues
```

I tried to add the groups that I see in the regular terminal to the same user, but from the VSCode terminal with no luck, as that VSCode terminal neither was able to find the neccesary commands:

```
$ usermod -aG docker $USER
bash: usermod: orden no encontrada (USERMOD ORDER NOT FOUND)
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
bash: sudo: orden no encontrada (SUDO ORDER NOT FOUND)
```

I also tried forcing `source ~/.bashrc` config file from VSCode console, there was no error, but the behaviour kept the same.

Don't understand where does this discrepancy comes from. I have installed VSCode on several machines a lot of times before and never have seen this behaviour. Any ideas?.

**VSCode version:**

```
Version: 1.76.2
Commit: ee2b180d582a7f601fa6ecfdad8d9fd269ab1884
Date: 2023-03-14T17:57:21.103Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.15.0-70-generic
Sandboxed: No
```

**Linux box info:**

```
$ cat /etc/linuxmint/info 
RELEASE=21.1
CODENAME=vera
EDITION="Cinnamon"
DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 21.1 Vera"
DESKTOP=Gnome
TOOLKIT=GTK

$ cat /etc/upstream-release/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish"
```

Comment: how exactly did you install VS Code? Snap?

Comment: Can you run `hostname` in both terminals?

Comment: @user I installed VSCode from the SW Manager. I think is mostly the same as running "sudo apt install..." from the official jammy repo.

Comment: @Philippe both return the same: `coco-master` which is the name I gave to the box.

Comment: Can you share `/etc/os-release` in both terminals ?

Comment: @Philippe I have updated the question with the results of /etc/os-release in both terminals. They are also different. I really don't understand what's going on here. Looks like I'm running VSCode in a different host, but that's not the case.

Comment: Maybe you can share the result of `ifconfig` to see what network they are on.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after the questions that @Philippe made. If you run `cat /etc/os-release` in both terminals, you could see that they were completely different: the regular console showed the expected information, whereas the VSCode console showed:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Freedesktop SDK"
VERSION="22.08 (Flatpak runtime)"
VERSION_ID=22.08
ID=org.freedesktop.platform
PRETTY_NAME="Freedesktop.org SDK 22.08 (Flatpak runtime)"
BUG_REPORT_URL=https://gitlab.com/freedesktop-sdk/freedesktop-sdk/issues
```

There, the **"Flatpak runtime"** gave me the clue. I have never really deep dived into what "Flatpak" meant, and I usually install VSCode from the .deb file from the web, so that's why I've never run into this issue, but the package manager version (the one I installed this time) was the "Flatpak" one.

From Flatpak documentation:
*"With Flatpak, each application is built and run in an isolated environment, which is called the ‘sandbox’. Each sandbox contains an application and its runtime. By default, the application can only access the contents of its sandbox. Access to user files, network, graphics sockets, subsystems on the bus and devices have to be explicitly granted. Access to other things, such as other processes, is deliberately not possible."*

What this means is that if you install VSCode from a Flatpak, it is mostly as if you were running it inside a docker container with its own environment, and with access to some volumes, but not to the entire system. This is why my VSCode terminal was reporting that many differences, because they were in effect different systems.

**Solution:** Uninstall package manager generic Flatpak version, and install the website system-specific version. Problem solved.